# How do I contract a selection of all pixels in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, selections

I have a series of images with a 1px border included in the picture. I need to get rid of that border. The logical route seemed to be `Select > All` and then `Select > Modify > Contract...` by 1 px. Unfortunately, when all pixels in a layer are selected, Photoshop (CS6 in my case) greys out all `Select > Modify` option but `Border...`. This seems to be an ancient 'bug', introduced in Ps CS3.

How can I work around this 'bug', preferably in a way that allows me to automate the process in an action?

Comment: I cant believe this bug still exists...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about the Trim feature? If the pixel border around the images is a solid colour or transparent Trim would work. You might have to play around with it a bit, but you should be able to use it to do what you are asking.

`Image > Trim...`

[image]

Comment: Useful and the superior option in case the border is a single colour. Unfortunately, there's slight variations.

Comment: What about an action to retract the canvas size by 1px?

Answer (score 2):

A quick workaround is to use the one `Modify` option still available: `Border`. `Border` for the amount of pixels you want to trim off the image, reverse the selection (`Select > Inverse` or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl/Option</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>) and `Image > Crop`.

Comment: This almost works, but it doesn't give a solid 1px line, it seems to be slightly anti-aliased.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow these steps:

1. Select - All
2. Select - Modify - Border (1px)
3. Select - Inverse
4. **Select - Modify - Contract**

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kZH2gT5dGmY.

Janie News explains how to contract a selection. I think she is using a PC.

Use CMD-click when selecting the layer with the selection prior to using Select -> Contract

Comment: Hello Peggy and thanks for the contribution! Let us know if you have any questions